# Can WordPress Multisite work like a regular site?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm helping someone that has no technical experiences with their WordPress site, and I realized he may have accidentally set it up as a multisite.

My question is if I don't want to go through all the trouble of changing the site back to a regular WordPress site, can I just treat and use the site as a regular WordPress site? Or will there be any technical difficulties later on? 
(the site just displays some content and can put items in shopping cart to buy them)

And since it's a multisite and I only have admin power and not super admin, to install plugins I would have to either ask for access to the super admin account or have the person install the plugins for me, right?

Lastly, how would I access and change the `wp-content/` files to customize (css/html/js) the templates myself? Do I just download Filezilla to grab the files and change them and upload them back? Or is there a better way to do this?
And would I need super admin power to do this and what additional information do I need to set up the Filezilla besides the site url, my admin account and password?

Sorry for so many questions on here, please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he may have accidentally set it up as a multisite.

This sounds weird. Setting up a multisite is not something you do accidently.
I would suggest you ask access through ftp (FileZilla should do, and you do not need to be super admin). To see if it's multisite or not, you can look at the [.htaccess file](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) or [wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Enable_Multisite_.2F_Network_Ability). If you really do not need the multisite, it's best to [revert back to a single install](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/uninstall-multisite/).

Now, to answer your questions,

> can I just treat and use the site as a regular WordPress site?

No, you can't, especially not if you are not network admin. You need this to upgrade WP, plugins and the theme. Keeping the installation up-to-date is crucial for security.

> to install plugins I would have to either ask for access to the super
>   admin account or have the person install the plugins for me, right?

Being able to install and update plugins from within the WordPress Admin is convenient. Technically, however, you can also do so through FTP: simply add the plugins to /wp-content/plugins/ and the themes to /wp-content/themes/. You can then activate these on the site.

> how would I access and change the wp-content/ files to customize
>   (css/html/js) the templates myself?

FileZilla indeed. If you have access to the network you can edit these in the WP admin too, but I personally prefer to do so with an editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

> what additional information do I need to set up the Filezilla besides
>   the site url, my admin account and password?

You can't use your WordPress password for this, you need to have FTP access, and even better sFTP (encrypted). This is something the host should provide. Perhaps [these tutorials](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/) may be helpful.

GL with it!